# Required to capture the Performance monitor details from Chrome Dev tools into Java program

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a selenium test written java.
As part of the test i am trying to capture/retrieve the current 'CPU Usage' and 'JS heap size' of the browser and print it in console.
Is there a way to achieve this in java code by executing a JavaScript command or something.

•   CPU usage - what percentage of your CPU the site is using.
•   JS heap size - how much memory (in Megabytes) is being used by the app.

I always run my test in Chrome browser. Please consider my test scenario contains a simple login for a website.

[image: Screenshot of performance monitor]

Comment: can you share the html if possible?

Comment: this is for any html page. this performance monitor details are not coming as part of html. and i understand selenium can only interact with the browser itself. hence i need any other api which can do this job just by importing into my selenium code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As selenium can only interact with the browser itself, I don't think you can you can use it to get CPU usage from the server, and same with the JS heap size.

You could get the **Java** heap size created by your script; that will be available to selenium.  But I don't think you can get info about server usage without some other tool or looking at the server directly.

### EDIT

After a bit more thinking and searching you should be able to get your **JS** heap size using Selenium's JavascriptExecutor, so you should be able to get the value of `window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize` at any stage during testing. Below is the code.

```
  public static Double reportMemoryUsage(WebDriver webDriver, String message) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.gc()");
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return Double usedJSHeapSize = (Double) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver)
            .executeScript("return window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize/1024/1024");
    LOGGER.info("Memory Usage at " + usedJSHeapSize + " MB.”);
 }
```

If you call this method once at the beginning of your test suite and once at the end, the difference between the  two usedJSHeapSize values should provide the Heap space invoked by your Selenium script.

I am forcing garbage collection before taking usedJSHeapSize, to make sure the there is no garbage information collected. To enable gc function on window, you will have to set the `-js-flags=--expose-gc` option.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("-js-flags=--expose-gc");
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Let me know if you still want to find the **Java** heap size from your script and I think I can come up with something for that.

Comment: Can you share the details about getting the JAVA heap size created by the script. the mentioned performance details are required only for the script which i run and not from the server side.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a bit more investigation I thin you can get the **JS** heap size using `javascriptExecutor`; see the edit I added to my answer.

Comment: Lot many thanks Peck.  when i run the given method it returns a negative value like "- 6.761272430419922 MB " . i should be getting a positive value like in attached picture. sorry if i am not detailing the my issue properly.

Comment: Does it just appear this way because of how I’ve written the message? LOGGER.info("Memory Usage at " + message + " - " + usedJSHeapSize + " MB "); notice the “ - “ before usedJSHeapSize. This could  be confusing especially if you don’t pass in anything for the “message” argument. In that case the output would look like “Memory usage at  - 7.8629 MB.” I’ll amend the logger statement at the bottom of my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Awesome! I ran your program in a for loop and performed some action on the page to increase and decrease the JSHeap size. And i can see the values are matching between the console and browser. I got my required answer here. i am sorry for that confusion on - appearing before the value. But now i understood.

Comment: Great! If you don’t mind go ahead and accept the answer when you get the chance.

Comment: Hi, any help on getting the CPU Usage? initially it was not mandate but now i need to capture CPU Usage as well.